# How do I view wireless networks?

Tags: wireless

I'm a new Ubuntu user and trying to connect to the internet. When I boot my machine with Windows it shows wireless networks to connect to but when I boot with Ubuntu there are none shown. Is there something I need to do to see wireless networks?

I am using the Killer AC 1535 wireless card and installed the drivers via usb and followed all the directions posted here: http://www.killernetworking.com/support/knowledge-base/17-linux/20-killer-wireless-ac-in-linux-ubuntu-debian.

Everything seemed to go ok but still no wireless...

Update: My version is 14.04.3 LTS. When I enter the modinfo command nothing happens, it just goes to another line without saying or doing anything.

Thanks!

[lspci results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ1Cz.jpg)

Comment: What? You installed drivers through USB? How did you do that?

Comment: Did you try connecting to WiFi before installing the drivers?

Comment: I mean that I copied the files from my machine booted in windows with internet onto a thumbdrive then copied the appropriate files into the folders specified in said link...I thought that part went without saying...

Comment: Of course I tried to connect to the internet without going out of my way to install drivers...

Comment: What does this tell us? `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && demsg | grep ath` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: I added the response above in the image link called "Response Image Here".

Thanks

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: Let's verify your exact device: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Thanks.

Comment: Ok, results from lspci are posted in image above. I couldn't find anything on my version but it's a recent install if that helps any. Thanks

Comment: Find and post your version with: `lsb_release -d` Also run and post: `modinfo ath10k_pci | grep 003E`

Comment: My version is 14.04.3 LTS. When I enter the modinfo command nothing happens, it just goes to another line without saying or doing anything.

Comment: Anyone have ideas on how to solve this? Thanks!